# Upon success response with data from Ajax call, process additional function as well

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to call function upon successful response from  ajax call.

Here both functions:

```
      function waggle() {
       var element = $(this);
          var tmpClass = element.attr('class');
          element.removeClass();
          setTimeout(function() {
            element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
            element.addClass(tmpClass).addClass('start-now');
          }, 10);
    }

    function auto_load(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {room_id:'$r_room_id',site_id:'$r_site_id'},
      url: 'cart_counter.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#cart_buble').html(data);
        waggle();
      }
    });
  }
```

This does update **#cart_buble** div as expected with the number in the cart however doesn't execute **waggle** function which is responsible for calling css transition effect.

Both functions are working fine seperately.

Comment: You do not put all the code, but as the indentation is different, it maybe could be a problem with function scope. Could you put all the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this` variable is the problem here. 
This kind of function declaration can change the data stored in `this` variable up to where the function is executed.

Try this way

```js
function waggle() {
       var element = $(...); // <--- Query your element instead of using `this`
          var tmpClass = element.attr('class');
          element.removeClass();
          setTimeout(function() {
            element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
            element.addClass(tmpClass).addClass('start-now');
          }, 10);
    }

    function auto_load(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {room_id:'$r_room_id',site_id:'$r_site_id'},
      url: 'cart_counter.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#cart_buble').html(data);
        waggle();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @pepe_witch. I gave added div id in (...) brackets and now waggle function is playing all the time instead only on success, any idea?

Comment: Sorted, I had to add if clause to check if data changed as otherwise my auto_load function was playing waggle function constantly instead of only playing it once data changed.